# morphism between universal elliptic curves

Tags: elliptic-curves, modular-forms

I was trying to go through an exercise ($7.9.3$) in the book "A first course in modular forms" (Diamond, Shurman). We are trying to proof that the hecke operators $T_p$ are defined over $\mathbb{Q}$, I give now some notation:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\Gamma(N)=\{\gamma\in\text{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z}): \gamma\equiv\left[\begin{matrix}1 &0 \\ 0& 1\end{matrix}\right] \text{mod}(N)\}\\
\Gamma_0(N)=\{\gamma\in\text{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z}): \gamma\equiv\left[\begin{matrix}a &b \\ 0& c\end{matrix}\right] \text{mod}(N)\}\\
\Gamma_1(N)=\{\gamma\in\text{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z}): \gamma\equiv\left[\begin{matrix}1 &c \\ 0& 1\end{matrix}\right] \text{mod}(N)\}\\
\Gamma_{1,0}(N,p)=\Gamma_1(N)\cap\Gamma_0(p)     
\end{split}
\end{equation}
We denote respectively with $X(N)$, $X_0(N)$, $X_1(N)$ and $X_{1,0}(N,p)$ the associated modular curves. We know that all these curves are defined over $\mathbb{Q}$, we called them $X_{\dots}(\dots)_{alg}$.
The point (d) is where I'm stuck, I'll cite the text

> Let $\tau'=p\tau$ and let $j'=j(\tau')$, both in $\mathbb{Q}(X_{1,0}(N,p)_{alg})$ and thus is $\mathbb{Q}(j,E_j[Np])$. Show that there is a morphism $\phi\colon E_j\rightarrow E_{j'}$ with kernel $<Q_{\tau,N}>$, taking $Q_{\tau,Np}$ to $Q_{\tau',N}$ and defined over some Galois extension $\mathbb{L}$ of $\mathbb{Q}(j,E_j[Np])$. Here the second subscript of each $Q$ denots its order.

$E_j$ was defined as a curve over $\mathbb{C}(j)$ by the equation $y^2=4x^3-\frac{27j}{j-1728}x-\frac{27j}{j-1728}$ and
\begin{equation}
Q_{\tau,N}=\bigg(\frac{g_2(\tau)}{g_3{\tau}}\wp_\tau(1/N),\bigg(\frac{g_2(\tau)}{g_3{\tau}}\bigg)^{3/2}\wp_\tau'(1/N)\bigg)
\end{equation}

I thank in advance for any help.

Comment: that was the first thing i tried but i don't understand why the corresponding lattice is $\frac{1}{p}\mathbb{Z}+\tau\mathbb{Z}$ and not $\frac{1}{N}\mathbb{Z}+\tau\mathbb{Z}$, it seemed to me that on the lattice we were adding $<\frac{1}{N}>$.

Comment: Right sorry, I didn't pay attention carefully. Looks like a typo, kernel $\langle Q_{\tau,p}\rangle$

Comment: yeah, i think that too. thank you.